# Why isn't this parser for tracking parentheses working?

Tags: java, regex, parsing

I was wondering why the parser portion(separated out) does not work. It is printing everything as if I did not add the parser. In my original code(not parser indicated), it converts (a)*n or (a)*{n} to \pochhammer{a}{n} but it does not do this for patterns with nested parentheses inside the a. The parser is supposed to ignore the nested parentheses in something like "(a(b))*n or (a(b))*{n} and print out \pochhammer{a(b)}{n}. Thanks.

```
while (scanner.hasNextLine()) {
        String line = scanner.nextLine();
        Pattern cpochhammer = Pattern.compile("\\(([^)]+)\\)_\\{([^}]+)\\}");
        Matcher pochhammer = cpochhammer.matcher(line);
        StringBuffer rplcmntBfr = new StringBuffer();
```

parser:

```
        char toCheck = '(';
        char toChecko = ')';
        int count = 0;
        for (int i = 0; i < line.length(); i++) {
            if (line.charAt(i) == toCheck) {
                count++;
            }
            if (line.charAt(i) == toChecko) {
                count--;
            }
            if (count == 0 && line.indexOf(")_") == i) {
                Pattern dnestedParen = Pattern.compile("\\((.+)\\)_\\{([^}]+)\\}");
                Matcher dmnestedParen = dnestedParen.matcher(rplcmntBfr.toString());
                if (dmnestedParen.find())
                    dmnestedParen.appendReplacement(rplcmntBfr,
                            "\\\\pochhammer{$1}{$2}");
            }
        }
```

end parser

```
while (pochhammer.find()) {
            pochhammer.appendReplacement(rplcmntBfr,
                    "\\\\pochhammer{$1}{$2}");
        }
        pochhammer.appendTail(rplcmntBfr);
        Pattern npochhammer = Pattern.compile("\\(([^)]+)\\)_(.)");
        Matcher ppochhammer = npochhammer.matcher(rplcmntBfr.toString());
        rplcmntBfr.setLength(0);
```

parser:

```
        count = 0;
        for (int i = 0; i < line.length(); i++) {
            if (line.charAt(i) == toCheck) {
                count++;
            }
            if (line.charAt(i) == toChecko) {
                count--;
            }
            if (count == 0 && line.indexOf(")_") == i) {
                Pattern nestedParen = Pattern.compile("\\((.+)\\)_(.)");
                Matcher mnestedParen = nestedParen.matcher(rplcmntBfr.toString());
                if(mnestedParen.find())
                    mnestedParen.appendReplacement(rplcmntBfr,
                        "\\\\pochhammer{$1}{$2}");
            }
        }
```

end parser

```
        while (ppochhammer.find()) {
            ppochhammer.appendReplacement(rplcmntBfr,
                    "\\\\pochhammer{$1}{$2}");
        }
        ppochhammer.appendTail(rplcmntBfr);
        writer.println(rplcmntBfr);
    }
```

Comment: What does your debugger show?

Comment: Detecting nested parens with regex is very difficult unless using an extended regex library that will allow for recursion or counting of pairs.  Perl's library is capable, not certain if Java's can handle that.

Comment: Any particular reason for this  if (count == 0 && line.indexOf(")_") == i) instead of    if (count == 0 && lne.charAt(i)==toChecko&& line.charAt(i+1) == "_" )??  As it is written it scans then entire line repeatedly on every run of the loop.  If you really want to use indexOf do it before the loop and store the index.  This also assumes only one pair per line as written.  No idea what you are parsing though.

Comment: Third time now. If you are NOT validating the text and are trying to **ignore** nested paren's/braces, is simply _parens_ - _not parens_ - _parens_ `\([^()]+\)` Whats wrong?

Answer (score 3):

Because it isn't a parser. It's a scanner, using regular expressions, and regular expressions cannot count anything, let alone parentheses. To parse nested syntax of any kind you need an explicit or implicit stack, and that takes you out of the land of regular expressions altogether into the world of parsers. Have a look at the Dijkstra Shunting-yard algorithm, or recursive descent expression parsing.